# Swift 3 : Tableview select row goes to different navigation views

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Trying to create a simple app with Swift 3, using Xcode 8.2. Would like to have a hierarchy as follows:

```
Tab-bar View 
-->TableView
----->TableView
--------->View
--------->TableView
--------->etc.
----->TableView
----->View
-->TableView
```

For example, main tab bar should have a tableView controller embedded inside a navigation controller. Clicking on a certain cell (index.path) should lead to a separate tableview or viewcontroller that itself can branch off into its own series of 'child' tables. The tables should be dynamic, and all have navigation control that leads back 'pop' to the most previous table/view controller.

Currently, for the main tableview, I have:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == List_Database_Indexes.employees {
        let myWebView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Employees") as! UITableViewController
        //self.present(myWebView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Employees", sender: nil)

    }
```

This works to bring up the Employees UITableViewController but does not have the navigationbar controller at the top. For example, from apple, if you click on in the image below 'General' row, you are lead to a navigation tableview that takes you to Passlock code, which takes you to Auto-lock, all with navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == List_Database_Indexes.employees {
        let myWebView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Employees") as! UITableViewController
        //self.present(myWebView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Employees", sender: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myWebView, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is delegate method. so it will apply on all of the cell for table because we have bind delegate to tableview. cell is subview of table view.

you have to give condition for wether the cell is selected or not..

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == //index of that cell {
        let Employee = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Employees") as! UITableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Employee, animated: true)
    }
}
```